# Segfault when running JavaFX and Swing from IntelliJ

Tags: swing, intellij-idea, javafx, java

When running the following minified example from IntelliJ 2016.1 Community edition, I **always** encounter a segmentation fault:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Repro extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame swingFrame = new JFrame();
        swingFrame.setTitle("Repro start");
        swingFrame.setSize(200, 350);
        swingFrame.setVisible(true);

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setMinHeight(200);
        root.setMinWidth(350);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

The environment is as follows:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- openjdk-8 (1.8.0_u66 build 17)
- openjfx-8 (8u60-b27-4)
- IntelliJ 2016.1 Community Edition (build #IC-145.258)

The issue is not reproducible by running `javac` into `java`
The problem also does not show when running through oraclejdk (1.8.0_u77-b03)

For reference the "output" of the program is as follows:

```
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (safepoint.cpp:712), pid=16937, tid=140197878814464
#  fatal error: Illegal threadstate encountered: 6
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b17) (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b17 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/vogel612/.../hs_err_pid16937.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

Process finished with exit code 134
```

The problem persists after running `ulimit -c unlimited` and restarting IntelliJ

As requested, the error log for one such execution is available at [this gist.](https://gist.github.com/Vogel612/897d891cccdd8cd0248168ed79988c6b)

How can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: Following make not much sense. `I was able to get someone to run it (Oracle JDK) for me under Windows`. You encounter a problem with `OpenJDK under Ubuntu`. To confirm the error you ask someone to run `Oracle JDK under Windows`. What does it confirm? `It does not happen under Windows` or `it does not happen with Oracle JDK`? Try first `Oracle JDK` under `Ubuntu`.

Comment: While this obviously does not justify a JVM crash, Swing code is not supposed to be run outside the AWT event dispatch thread.  I would be interested in learning whether the crash occurs when the Swing code is placed in an EventQueue.invokeLater or EventQueue.invokeAndWait call, like it's supposed to be.

Comment: @SubOptimal it took a while, but I cannot repro when I set the executing jdk to oracle 1.8.0_u77 (which is the currently available from webupd8team's ppa)

Comment: @VGR the problem persists after moving the call to `swingFrame.setVisible` into `SwingUtilites.invokeLater`

Comment: If it does not occure with Oracle JDK it might be a bug in the OpenJDK. Could you please post the information from `hs_err_pid16937.log` at which point in the JVM it crashes.

Comment: @SubOptimal since that's a rather huge wall of text to include I'd prefer to link that to an external pasting service...

Comment: **1)** Does `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` and `/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` point to the same file? **2)** From which location did you install the packages? `http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/pool/main/o/` does not show any OpenJDK / OpenJFX packages. **3)** I'm not sure if it's possible to mix different OpenJDK (1.8.0_u66 build 17) and OpenJFX (8u60-b27-4) versions.

Comment: @SubOptimal **1)** Yes, in fact the one in `lib/jvm/...` symlinks to the other one
**2)** the packages are installed from canonical / main
**3)** neither am I, but they are both from main and both on the "current" version available. I assume that mixing the versions like that shouldn't be a problem in and of itself (else they would've been provided differently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can be reproduced outside IntelliJ as follow.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Repro().main(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

running `java -cp . Main` on Ubuntu 15.10 with

> openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

produces the same fatal error. Whereas running `java -cp . Repo` does not fail.

running `java -cp . Main` on CentOS 7 with

> openjdk version "1.8.0_77"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

opens the Swing JFrame and the JavaFX Pane.

Seems this issue is related to that specific OpenJDK version and the way the class `Repo` is called.

**edit** If you can't switch to another Java version there is a possible "workaround". (based on this [post](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/javafx-toolkit-not-initialized-solved/))

Amend your `Repro.java` as below and it will not fail on `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new JFXPanel(); // the "workaround" to initialize the toolkit
    JFrame swingFrame = new JFrame();
    ...
```

Comment: wow.. I'd have never expected that :/ Unfortunately the "offending" code is inside a unit-test. As such it's impossible for me to change how the code is called or require an initialization of the toolkit (as in your workaround)... For now I'll have to switch jdk then... alas.

Comment: @Vogel612 Updating the JDK in that case is the preferable solution. Except there would be other contrains to keep it.

Comment: I was facing same error, this works in ubuntu19 - oracle jdk build 1.8.0_251-b08.  Can some one explain how does it work